# HTML/CSS :Focus Selector and Tab Key Not Working in Firefox / Windows 7

Tags: html, css, firefox, focus

I am trying to create a drop-down menu with only HTML and CSS that is initially hidden, then appears onscreen after the user hovers with the mouse or tabs onto the link.

The hover aspect works fine, but I can't seem to get my menu to work properly using only the keyboard or tab key.

Here is the snippet:

```css
#menu {display: none;}

a:focus + #menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<a href="#menu">Drop Down Menu</a>


<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Test Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Tabbing onto the 'Drop Down Menu' link does show the hidden links, but I cannot tab onto the sub links once they show up on screen. I tried adding the tabindex="0" attribute to all the div, ul, and li elements and that did not seem to solve the problem either.

I'm new to web design, maybe I'm missing something. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are having the issue because when you `display: none` an element, it essentially removes it from the page from a users perspective, and the DOM is still remembering those elements as not being a part of the page even after you dynamically add them back.  Also, some would say using `display: none` like that negatively impacts accessibility:
https://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/

Here is some JavaScript that gives you the effect you are looking for with your specific code:

```
<style>

.hide {
   position: absolute !important;
   top: -9999px !important;
   left: -9999px !important;
}

</style>

<a href="#menu">Drop Down Menu</a>


<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Test Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  (function() {
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

    //convert list of a elements into an array
    var anchor = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));

    menu.classList.add('hide');

    //loop through a elements, removing hide class from #menu on focus
    anchor.forEach(function(c) {
      c.addEventListener('focus', function() {
        menu.classList.remove('hide');
      });
      c.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        menu.classList.add('hide');
      });
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My whole reason for doing this is specifically for user accessibility, so I want to stay away from JavaScript, if possible, for basic features. I kept googling after I posted and came across information that mentioned the DOM excluding display: none elements upon page load.  However, I was able to get tab key access with display: none, :focus, and tabindex in IE8. So I'm not sure how or why IE allows an initially hidden element to be tabbed after the page load whereas Firefox doesn't.

Comment: No problem.  Well without the JavaScript the menu would never have been hidden, making it accessible to screen readers etc.  There is a performance hit but nothing in this case substantial enough to make a difference but I agree, if it can be done with CSS that is the way to go.  Let me know if you find a CSS solution!